# how to get the next 10 elements in an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to php. While I was doing a project I got stuck in a  place. Consider that I have an array with 100 elements.

```
for ( $i=0;$i<100;$i++) {
    $related = array();
    for($j=0;$j<100;$j++){
        if($g[$i] != $gs[$j])
            $related[] = $gs[$j];
    }
```

What I want is to get the next 10 elements. How can I get it?

Comment: you need ti get 0 to 10 elements  in array ?

Comment: next 10 elements from ???

Comment: It's very unclear what you want! Also please show us your **full** code! The for loop isn't even closed in this code. Add what you have now and what you expect

Comment: @Amanda. Do you want to get next 10 values from a particular position of array? Please! would you clear a little?

Comment: @offshore- yes i am looking for the next 10 values from the current position of element

Answer (score 0):

You may create function :

```
public function getElements($array100, $count, $from){
    $related = array();
    $j = 0;
    for ( $i = $from; $i < $from+$count; $i++) {
            $related[$j] = $array100[$i];
            $j++;
    }
    return $related;
}
```

and you can call this function anywhere like :

```
getElements($array,10,45);
```

Answer (score 0):

As your question is not very clear, I take you idea as to get the next 10 elements from the matched and the include the matched one.

```
for ( $i=0;$i<100;$i++) {
    $related = array();

    // here let j start from i to avoid invalid compute
    for($j=$i;$j<100;$j++){
        if($g[$i] != $gs[$j]){
            $length = min(10, 100-$j); // here to avoid the cross border access exception
            $related[] = array_slice($gs, $j, $length);
        }
    }
```